# Unable to play Soundcloud song on my webpage

Tags: soundcloud

I am trying to play a Soundcloud song on my webpage.  I am just trying to test out using the API but I don't seem to be getting anywhere.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?  Soundcloud will authorize me and will show an object for the song, but will not play it.  Not sure how to look up more information, the information for beginners is tough to find or doesn't working.  Trying to do this from developers.soundcloud.com

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'entered my id from the registered app here'
});

var track_url = 'https://soundcloud.com/aviciiofficial/hope-theres-someone-1';
SC.oEmbed(track_url, { auto_play: true }).then(function(oEmbed) {
  console.log('oEmbed response: ', oEmbed);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the API does not allow you to get the track contents. Unfortunately this is not very clear from the documentation. Nor is it very clear when a track is allowed to be accessed through the API and when it's not.

Find the track id:

`curl "https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=https://soundcloud.com/aviciiofficial/hope-theres-someone-1&client_id=..."
{"status":"302 - Found","location":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/255863316?client_id=..."}`

`wget "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/255863316?client_id=..."
--2016-04-25 11:05:01--  https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/255863316?client_id=...
Resolving api.soundcloud.com... 93.184.220.127
Connecting to api.soundcloud.com|93.184.220.127|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2016-04-25 11:05:01 ERROR 403: Forbidden.`

This one is allowed to be accessed without a 403 error, and I liked the title of it: https://soundcloud.com/paradoxeodstl/error-403-prod-boxinwoxin